# Strcmp not with working data in mysql

Tags: mysql, c, string, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <my_global.h>

void replace(char * o_string, char * s_string, char * r_string) {
      char buffer[1024];
      char * ch;
      if(!(ch = strstr(o_string, s_string)))
              return;
    strncpy(buffer, o_string, ch-o_string);
      buffer[ch-o_string] = 0;
    sprintf(buffer+(ch - o_string), "%s%s", r_string, ch + strlen(s_string));
      o_string[0] = 0;
      strcpy(o_string, buffer);
      return replace(o_string, s_string, r_string);
 }

int main()
{
    MYSQL *pConn;
    MYSQL_RES *pRes;
    MYSQL_ROW aRow;
    MYSQL_FIELD *field;
    int nfields, iCounter;
    pConn = mysql_init(NULL);
    char aPassword[1024]="";    
    if (pConn == NULL){
            printf("Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(pConn), mysql_error(pConn));
              exit(1);
        }
    if(mysql_real_connect(pConn, 0, "root",aPassword,"data",0,NULL,0) == NULL){
        printf("Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(pConn), mysql_error(pConn));
             exit(1);
        }       
    char *info;
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    printf("<html><body>"); 
    info = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    char sub[20]="";
    int nsub;
    char teacher[20]="";
    char room[20]="";
    int nroom;
    int count=0;    
    char *token;
    char arr[5][20];
    char data[1024];
    char aCommand[1024];
    char data2[1024];
    replace(info,"%20"," ");
    replace(info,"name=","");
    token = strtok(info, " ");
    while(token!=NULL){
        strcpy(arr[count],token);   
        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    if(count==5){
        strcat(arr[0]," ");     
        strcat(arr[0],arr[1]);
        strcpy(sub,arr[0]);
        strcpy(teacher,arr[2]);
        strcat(arr[3]," ");     
        strcat(arr[3],arr[4]);
        strcpy(room,arr[3]);
    }
    if(count==4){
        strcat(arr[0]," ");     
        strcat(arr[0],arr[1]);
        strcpy(sub,arr[0]);
        strcpy(teacher,arr[2]);
        strcpy(room,arr[3]);

    }
    strcat(teacher," ");
    strcat(teacher,room);
    strcat(sub," ");
    strcat(sub,teacher);
    puts(sub);
    sprintf(aCommand,"select * from Schedule");
    mysql_query(pConn, aCommand);
    pRes = mysql_store_result(pConn);
    nfields = mysql_num_fields(pRes);   
    while ((aRow = mysql_fetch_row(pRes))){
        if(strncmp(aRow[2],sub,strlen(sub)-1)==0)
            puts("YS");
        else
            puts("NO");
    }   

    mysql_free_result(pRes);
    mysql_close(pConn);
    printf("</body></html>");
    return 0;
}
```

That's the whole code. I don't know where the problem is. After I parsed the query string and display them, it seems that the field and the parsed string are equal. But I've been trying to use `strcmp` and they just won't work. What could be the error?

Comment: Extraneous newline? Missing `NUL`-terminator?

Comment: Show more code. You're doing something wrong, and you haven't shown enough for us to tell what.

Comment: @sinsedrix Why would he need to do that? If you're an experienced C programmer, you must know that literal strings always get null terminated.

Comment: print the arow[11]: printf("%d\n", arow[11]);

Comment: @Barmar I used `strcat` to create the char array string `hellothere`.

Comment: Good for you. Now show some code so we can help you.

Comment: @Barmar I've already updated the code.

Comment: It's still not clear. You have three different variables, how are you comparing them to one database field? Why won't you just show us the code?

Comment: Instead of `puts(sub)`, try `printf("|%s|%s|\n", sub, aRow[2])`, so you'll see if there are any extra spaces. Also, why are you subtracting 1 from `strlen()` in your `strncmp()`? Aren't these both null-terminated strings, why not use ordinary `strcmp()`?

Comment: @Barmar they are just the same whenever I try to print them both.

Comment: I am concerned that the `"%20"` might need to be `"%19"` to avoid over running your many char arrays of size 20.

Comment: `char *info;` should be `const char *info;` to avoid undefined behavior in using `info` derived from `info = getenv("QUERY_STRING");`.  I think you get this UB then in `replace(info, ...`.

Comment: @chux If I do it, it erases the whole string. I used `%20` because that is what's printed when I print the whole query string. There is no `%19`.

Comment: Concerning %20 - my mistake - I read scanf() when it plainly reads sprintf().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I tried using `strstr` to find the string that only matches with the data in the MySQL table. It doesn't match the whole string so I just modified the program. Instead of matching the whole string, I just used a part of the string to match with the data in the table.